# "Consolidating memory is not instantaneous or even {momentary/inevitable}" - Why is inevitable the correct choice?

Tags: word-choice, exam-questions

> Consolidating memory is not instantaneous or even _____: every memory must be encoded and moved from short-term to long-term storage, and some of these memories are, for whatever reason, more vividly imprinted than others.
>
> A. salutary
>   B. deliberate
>   C. sequential
>   D. momentary
>   E. inevitable

This is a GRE exam question.
I know the meaning of the "momentary" and "inevitable" as I looked them up in the dictionary but as I read the whole paragraph again and again with "momentary" and "inevitable", both sound correct. I cannot find what clues make us to choose "inevitable" (as the reference said) as the answer and not "momentary".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final part of the sentence is a red herring, and the sentence could stop at "long-term storage." How vividly a memory is imprinted is not shown to have any correlation with how long it takes to consolidate it.

So moving that out of the way, the two clues are:

1. Consolidating memory is not instantaneous
2. every memory must be encoded and moved

The second clue tells us that there is a process required for the memory to be consolidated. This means that the process could be interrupted, for whatever reason, if it takes long enough for the process to occur. Going back to the first clue tells us that the consolidation does not happen right away. This means that there is, in fact, some span of time during which that process could be interrupted.

Taking those two clues into account, inevitable would be the word to choose, as the clues are telling us that there is no guarantee for memory consolidation.

Comment: In this type of GRE question, all parts of information will be needed.

Answer (score 3):

The two parts before the colon are complemented by two parts after the colon. "not  instantaneous" corresponds to "every memory must be encoded and moved from short-term to long-term storage"; there are several steps such as encoding and moving, and those take time. The second word before the colon corresponds to "and some of these memories are, for whatever reason, more vividly imprinted than others." If some are more vivid, then others are less vivid. Thus, vivid imprinting is not certain. So "not inevitable" matches the meaning.